# Uk law: appoint decision maker for child after death

Tags: united-kingdom, wills, guardianship

My partner and I are looking into options for appointing her sister as the primary decision maker in the unlikely event that we both die while our son is still young.

We feel her sister would be the best at making the most objective decision on whether her current circumstances, or either of the grandparents circumstances (at the time) would most suit becoming a guardian.

So we don’t necessarily want to appoint her as the guardian as she may live abroad when we hypothetically both die…

A bit morbid I know

Are there any options for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Talk to a lawyer

Tell them what you want to happen and they will draft a will for you that makes sure what you want to happen does happen. They will also raise possibilities that you haven’t though of yet: like what if your sister pre-deceases you, or what if you have more than just this child when you die etc.

Comment: Thanks! Seems simple enough!